# Почему в печатных текстах нет буквы Ё?

Tags: история, графика

Почему из письменного русского языка изгоняется буква Ё и является ли эта буква исконно русской?

Answer (score 3):

Употребление Ё давным-давно регламенторовано. 
Употребление обязательно в учебных изданиях, при написании собственных имен и в целях смыслоразличения. В остальных случаях следует придерживаться следующей рекомендации. Ё должно быть либо регулярно проставлено по всему тексту, либо нигде, кроме оговоренных выше случаев. Вполне разумная и понятная рекомендация.

Имена в документах вполне подпадают под это правило.

О чем говорит министр, не очень понятно. Я вот заинтересовался, а алфавит у нас вообще "законодательно" закреплён? Есть нормирующие документы, по которым учат детей и взрослых, но там этот вопрос достаточно проработан, см. выше.
В качестве маленькой шпильки. А нашему дражайшему Правительству за последние двадцать пять лет хоть одну проблему удалось "решить окончательно"? Только каждый год стрелки переводят и праздники новогодние двигают.

В обязательном употреблении Ё есть несомненный минус. Текст будет пестрить непривычными знаками. Потом ещё потребуют обязательной простановки ударений - читать можно учиться заново. Дело, конечно, привычки, привыкнем и к ёфицировнному тексту, но вот миллиард китайцев вообще не озабочены алфавитом, ничего, живут.

//----------- **UPD**

Карамзин не привносил Ё в русский.
До определенного времени полагали, что он первым использовал Ё в печатном издании (это тоже оказалось не совсем так), но изобретена она была Екатериной Дашковой или кем-то из её окружения. На заседании Императорской Академии наук перед Императрицей был поставлен вопрос о необходимости какого-то знака взамен сочетания IO, которым обозначали Ё до того (это, кстати, к вопросу, о том, что в русском Ё не было). Екатерина, которая была "подготовлена" Дашковой, самолично начертала первую букву Ё.

В Вики есть [версия](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0,_%D0%95%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0#.D0.92_.D0.BE.D0.BF.D0.B0.D0.BB.D0.B5), отличная от представленой тем, что там нет упоминания Императрицы. Но авторство Дашковой под сомнение не ставится.

Про реформу Луначарского - вообще околесина. Никаких новаций в отношении Ё там нет. Использование Ё сохранялось в случаях, оговариваемых ещё Гротом (с небольшими последующими измененими). Формулировки этих случаев почти однозначно соответствуют современным.

Comment: @tmp, Вы не правы в том, что обязательное употребление Ё минус. Раньше это было проблемой - вообще в русском языке есть только одна буква с надстрочным элементом - это й. И ничего. Как-то живем. А так будем два. В наборе текста на компьютере и типографии никто не умрет. А вот при написании от руки - да, там будет не очень удобно выводить еще две точки.

> простановки ударений

А это передергивание. В некоторых случаях приходится проставлять ударение. Например, выделять курсивом. Если есть двусмысленное прочтение.

Comment: Ничуть.
Во-первых, я не сказал, что постановка Ё есть минус. Я сказал что один конкретный минус я вижу. Про плюсы и другие минусы не говорил. 
Во-вторых, никакого передергивания. Простите, но требование обязательной простановки Ё не просто сродни требованию ставить ударения, оно многими (если не большинством) достаточно грамотных людей таковым и воспринимается. Ибо над Ё ударение не ставится. Поэтому весь текст обычно и воспринимается как изобилующий поставленными ударениями.

Comment: А аргументация типа "никто не умрет" одинаково годится за обе стороны. Или вы можете показать умершего от того, что в обычных книгах нет Ё? 
Про две точки в рукописном тексте - это анекдот старый. Только там предлагалось экономить флакон чернил за пять лет. Сошлись на одной точке и флаконе за десять. Современные ёфикаторы, видимо, слишком молоды чтобы оценить юмор своих предложений.

Comment: Для меня лично - главное, чтобы Ё проставлялось в именах собственных. Остальное, в целом, некритично. Я долгое время даже и не подозревал, что правильно не Рерих, а Рёрих. Шредингера и Гете тоже пытались обидеть =)

Comment: В отношении иностранных собственных имен - вопрос очень спорный. Во-первых, там не Ё а ОЕ или Ö. Во-вторых, Имена не траскрибируются, а транслитерируются, а то и вовсе переводяся. 
Рёрих - согласен, тут без вариантов, имя обруселе. А вот с Гете и Шредингером... Ревнители фонетической точности забвают, что там твердые Г и Р. И не только они. Тогда уж ШРЭОДЫНГЭР и ГЭОТЭ. Точнее будет.

Comment: @tmp, как я ни произношу Гёте и Шрёдингер у меня Г и Т получаются твердыми ;) Насчет oe - это вообще отдельная история, т.к. это старинное написание фамилии. Между прочим, есть фамилии и с о-умлаутом: [Möller][1].

[1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D1%8E%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80,_%D0%90%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD

Comment: >Между прочим, есть фамилии и с о-умлаутом: Möller.  
  
ОЕ - это обычная замена ö. Так что любое слово, не только фамилия и не только старинная, может быть написано в двух вариантах. Аналогично АЕ и UЕ. 

Но речь о русском языке. И как можно произнести Г и Р твердыми, если за ними следует Ё, - я не представляю.  
Впрочем, речь даже и не об этом. Никто не доказал, что произношение на русском (как и на любом языке-мишени) должно свято следовать фонетике языка-источника. Хотел бы я посмотреть на того же немца, записывающего фамилию какого=нибудь Бздыщ-Жужжащенко из села Зачащощино.

Answer (score 1):

Не изгоняется,а просто не принято употреблять без надобности.
Есть еще одна проблема, связанная с этой буквой, - проблема автоматического распознания текста, распознания речи, генерации текста (перевода). Тот же пример с "передохнет от голода" напрашивается.

А некоторые компьютерные шрифты не содержат эту букву потому, что авторы не знают о ее существовании или считают устаревшей. Хотя тут, по-моему, не то "Сони", не то "Блэкберри" отличились - они забыли букву "й" на экранной клавиатуре их "андроида".

Answer (score 0):

Считаю сознательное игнорирование написания ё в тексте письма откровенным быдлячеством. В типографиях, где экономят на дополнительной литере в наборе, такое вольничество тоже неправильно. А исторические экскурсы с расследованиями, кто из царей как писал - отнесу к передёргиванию.